# What does redirect_to @client mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here I have a scaffold for clients, and in the create method in ClientsController,

```
if @client.save
  redirect_to @client
else
  render :action => "new"
end
```

Here what it means to redirect to an instance variable of Client class?

Also, in else, render renders the view for new if save fails. However, how does the controller keep the original input at the same place? (For example I fill the form and send it but fail to proceed, so it takes me back to the new client page with my original input at the right place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect_to @client` redirects to the `clients/show/1` directory. where 1 is the id of client. 
and `render :action => "new"` render the new action, for more detail see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: How does `render :action => "new"` remember your original input?

Comment: render the new action again but with error messages available